# (32bit or 64bit) Linux distro with !32bit! (U)EFI support?

Tags: windows, distribution-choice, uefi, 32bit

Is there a Linux distribution that supports 32bit-(U)EFI?
If so, which one and where do I find a bootable ISO?

I'd like to find a Linux distro for my HP Envy X2 which has an Intel Atom CPU and Windows 8 32bit and UEFI preinstalled. The CPU seems to support a 64bit architecture as well.

Comment: is this arm? if not... why?

Comment: The processor is Intel Atom. Suppose that means no arm architecture.

Comment: i guess so. its 32-bit? i wasnt aware there was such a thing as an x86 32-bit UEFI machine. is the processor 32-bit or is it just a 32-bit installation?

Comment: They are not very common but unfortunately they exist :-/

Comment: quite so. well... i have no idea. a good place to start learning would be at http://rodsbooks.com. i remember glancing past some mention of bit-width and architecture there, but it never pertained to me and didn't study it.

Comment: The site seems to have some useful tips in my direction. Especially adding a 32bit EFI bootloader to a 32bit Linux distribution. I'll take a closer look there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by UEFI support?

Comment: A Linux distro that has a 32bit EFI bootloader so it's possible to install it on a computer with UEFI.

Comment: I only know 64bit EFI bootloaders so far.

Comment: if you get very far through rod's books you'll come to realize you're not looking for a bootloader - the EFI *is* the loader - you just need to call your kernel somehow.

Comment: (U)EFI  has a builtin image (boot) loader.

Comment: mikeserv, could you post your comment as an answer (how to use rEFInd to install a Linux distro)? Your comment was somehow deleted, though very helpful!

Comment: I would suggest you to edit your question, asking for advice about 64bit Linux distributions that support 32bit EFI. :)

Comment: But my CPU is 32bit as well, not only the EFI. I think 64bit doesn't work in this case, does it?

Comment: Are you sure? It seems that this notebook have a `Intel Core™ M-5Y70`, and it is a 64-bit processor - http://ark.intel.com/products/83612/Intel-Core-M-5Y70-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz

Comment: Done, thx nwildner

Comment: [This](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows/Linux-on-the-Stream-tablet/td-p/4829188) may help (it's actually about same issue on the Stream 8). It uses Fedlet to chain load the desired image.

Comment: you can hardly find a 32-bit x86 CPU in the last decade. It's just the 32-bit UEFI that makes it hard to install 64-bit OSes. However [Ubuntu 15.10 and up support 32-bit EFI](http://askubuntu.com/a/715843/253474) which significantly simplify the process. [Installing linux on an 32bit UEFI only machine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155557/44425)

Answer (score 2):

Try Sparkylinux. I was able to load and install Sparkylinux on a Intel machine with atom processer with only uefi 32 bit support.