# Installing 32-bit Linux distribution on 32-bit Architecture with 32-bit UEFI

Tags: system-installation, boot-loader, uefi, 32bit, cpu-architecture

There's a lot of information on installing 64-bit Linux on 32-bit UEFI. It's a mess even here, but I've seen ways (rEFInd, etc).

But this laptop (HP Envy X2) has a 32-bit architecture and exclusively EFI (no CSM / legacy BIOS). So, how can I install a **32-bit** Linux distribution on a **32-bit** architecture, with **EFI** only?

At this point I'd be fine with pretty much any distribution. But if there's choice, I'd go with Arch-based, or Debian-based.

I have experience in GNU/Linux and installation / etc. I'm looking for EFI-specific help. The laptop currently runs Windows 10 with basically no drivers, but I have access to Debian and Windows on my desktop.

Thanks!

PS: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251705/32bit-or-64bit-linux-distro-with-32bit-uefi-support) is not a duplicate as the questioner is (I believe) wrong in believing that the X2's CPU supports 64-bit. The answer there is also merely a distribution name.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if any other distribution supports it? I'll try Ubuntu, it's just not my favorite (private, etc...)

Comment: You mentioned Arch as a preferred distribution. Unfortunately, Arch is phasing out support for 32-bit x86.

Answer (score 0):

Debian itself has a 32bit option and it supports uefi

Answer (score 0):

For those that may be reading this in the year 2019, this can be done with [ArchLinux32](https://archlinux32.org/).  See especially this section on [installing GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems):

> The section assumes you are installing GRUB for x86_64 systems. For
>   IA32 (32-bit) UEFI systems (not to be confused with 32-bit CPUs),
>   replace x86_64-efi with i386-efi where appropriate.